# Undefined external Scope ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm trying to display an external scope for the ui-grid footer using a directive. The external scope is shown correctly on the table, but the variable is undefined when I tried to access it in the link function. thoughts?

```
app.directive('testDir',[function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,    
        transclude: true,
        template: '<div>{{t1.val}}</div>',
        scope: {
          t1: '='
        },link: function(scope){
          console.log(scope); //=====>t1 is there in the console.
          console.log(scope.t1); //=====>t1 is undefined in console.          
        }
    };  
}]);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/qas0f23oE6RJOuYzrcOm?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you try to get the property before any value is assigned by its parent directive. Try changing your directive to this:

```
app.directive('testDir',['$timeout', function($timeout){
  return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,    
        transclude: true,
        template: '<div>{{t1.val}}</div>',
        scope: {
          t1: '='
        },link: function(scope){
          $timeout(function() {
              console.log(scope); //=====>t1 is there in the console.
              console.log(scope.t1); //=====>t1 is undefined in console.          
          });
        }
  };  
}]);
```